# DataTable clears itself after a for loop

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using a data table to store some data. After the for loop check the length of the data table, the data table clears itself. There is no data in it. Can you advise why is it so ? This is part part of a report that is using the DevExpress reporting engine to create the reports.

```
        DataTable ResultList = new DataTable();

        ResultList.Columns.Add("range");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("bpfrom");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("bpto");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("qualMemb");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("qualTurn");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("qualTurnPercent");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("grMemb");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("grTurn");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("grTurnPercent");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("totalamt");
        ResultList.Columns.Add("giftlevel");

        string[] fromrangelist = fromrange.Split(',');
        string[] torangelist = torange.Split(',');

        int j;

        if (fromrange == "")
        {
            DataRow dr = ResultList.NewRow();
            dr["range"] = 1;
            dr["bpfrom"] = 0;
            dr["bpto"] = 100000000; //biggest value
            dr["giftlevel"] = "ALL";
            ResultList.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        else
        {
            for (j = 0; j < fromrangelist.Length; j++)
            {
                DataRow dr = ResultList.NewRow();
                dr["range"] = j + 1;
                dr["bpfrom"] = Convert.ToDecimal(fromrangelist[j]);
                dr["bpto"] = Convert.ToDecimal(torangelist[j]);
                dr["giftlevel"] = "level:" + (j + 1).ToString() + "(" + fromrangelist[j] + "-" + torangelist[j] + ")";  
                ResultList.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        //Get ALL Total spend 
        decimal TotalSpend = Math.Round((from table1 in context.mmsspddtls
                                         where table1.mmsspdcpcd.Equals(cpcd) && table1.mmsspdbrcd.Equals(brcd)
                                          && table1.mmsspdtxdt >= fromtxdate && table1.mmsspdtxdt <= totxdate
                                          && (table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals(null) || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PS") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PE") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PR"))
                                          && (table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('1') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('5') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('P') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('T') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('A') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('L'))
                                          && !table1.mmsspdstfg.Equals('V')
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             totalamt = table1.mmsspdpram
                                         }).Sum(s => s.totalamt), 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < ResultList.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            decimal fromvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(ResultList.Rows[i]["bpfrom"]);
            decimal tovalue = Convert.ToDecimal(ResultList.Rows[i]["bpto"]);

            ResultList.Rows[i]["totalamt"] = TotalSpend;

            //Member Query that match the range
            var MemberQuery = (from table1 in context.mmscrdlogs
                               where table1.mmscdlcpcd.Equals(cpcd) && table1.mmscdlbrcd.Equals(brcd)
                               && table1.mmscdlstst.Equals('N') && table1.mmscdlbpis >= fromvalue && table1.mmscdlbpis <= tovalue
                               && table1.mmscdleddt >= fromexpiredate && table1.mmscdleddt <= toexpiredate
                               select new
                               {
                                   spendfr = fromvalue,
                                   spendto = tovalue,
                                   membercode = table1.mmscdlmbcd
                               }).Distinct();

            //Count of member in the range
            ResultList.Rows[i]["qualMemb"] = MemberQuery.Count();

            //member total spend in the range
            decimal qualTurn = 0;

            var qualQuery = (from table1 in context.mmsspddtls
                                from table2 in MemberQuery.Where(s => s.membercode == table1.mmsspdmbcd)
                                where table1.mmsspdcpcd.Equals(cpcd) && table1.mmsspdbrcd.Equals(brcd)
                                && table1.mmsspdtxdt >= fromtxdate && table1.mmsspdtxdt <= totxdate
                                && (table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals(null) || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PS") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PE") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PR"))
                                && (table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('1') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('5') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('P') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('T') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('A') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('L'))
                                && !table1.mmsspdstfg.Equals('V')
                                select new
                                {
                                    totalamt = table1.mmsspdpram
                                });

            if(qualQuery.Count() > 0)
            {
                qualTurn = Math.Round(qualQuery.Sum(s => s.totalamt), 2);
            }

            ResultList.Rows[i]["qualTurn"] = qualTurn;

            //member total spend% with total in the range

            if (qualTurn == 0)
                ResultList.Rows[i]["qualTurnPercent"] = 0;
            else
                ResultList.Rows[i]["qualTurnPercent"] = Math.Round((qualTurn / TotalSpend) * 100, 2);


            var MemberQueryGR = (from table1 in context.mmsspddtls
                                 from table2 in context.pxppludpxes.Where(s => s.pxppdxcpcd.Equals(table1.mmsspdcpcd) && s.pxppdxbrcd.Equals(table1.mmsspdbrcd) && s.pxppdxplcd.Equals(table1.mmsspdplcd))
                                 from table3 in context.mmssyspars.Where(s => s.mmssypcpcd.Equals(table1.mmsspdcpcd) && s.mmssypbrcd.Equals(table1.mmsspdbrcd))
                                 where table1.mmsspdcpcd.Equals(cpcd) && table1.mmsspdbrcd.Equals(brcd)
                                 && table2.pxppdxpx01 / (table3.mmssypbpmt / table3.mmssyppont) >= fromvalue
                                 && table2.pxppdxpx01 / (table3.mmssypbpmt / table3.mmssyppont) <= tovalue
                                 && table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("GR") && table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('2')
                                 && table1.mmsspdtxdt >= fromtxdate && table1.mmsspdtxdt <= totxdate
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     spendfr = fromvalue,
                                     spendto = tovalue,
                                     membercode = table1.mmsspdmbcd
                                 }).Distinct();

            //Count of GR member in the range
            ResultList.Rows[i]["grMemb"] = MemberQueryGR.Count();

            //GR member total spend in the range
            decimal grTurn = 0;

            if (MemberQueryGR.Count() > 0)
            {
                var grQuery = (from table1 in context.mmsspddtls
                          from table2 in MemberQueryGR.Where(s => s.membercode == table1.mmsspdmbcd)
                          where table1.mmsspdcpcd.Equals(cpcd) && table1.mmsspdbrcd.Equals(brcd)
                          && table1.mmsspdtxdt >= fromtxdate && table1.mmsspdtxdt <= totxdate
                          && (table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals(null) || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PS") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PE") || table1.mmsspdtxty.Equals("PR"))
                          && (table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('1') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('5') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('P') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('T') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('A') || table1.mmsspdplna.Equals('L'))
                          && !table1.mmsspdstfg.Equals('V')
                          select new
                          {
                              totalamt = table1.mmsspdpram
                          });

                if(grQuery.Count() > 0)
                {
                    grTurn = Math.Round(grQuery.Sum(s => s.totalamt), 2);
                }
            }

            ResultList.Rows[i]["grTurn"] = grTurn;


            //member total spend% with total in the range

            if (grTurn == 0)
                ResultList.Rows[i]["grTurnPercent"] = 0;
            else
                ResultList.Rows[i]["grTurnPercent"] = Math.Round((grTurn / TotalSpend) * 100, 2);


        }                 



        DataSource = ResultList;
    }
```

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it will be better for you to crate class to store data?

Comment: Maybe its a scope issue? Try `DataSource = ResultList.Clone();`

Comment: @user326608 But all the declaretions anf loops are within a method. When I check for the row count, there is one, untill it goes back to check the i++ condition

Comment: Wouldn't the loop exit after one iteration, if there is only one row?

Comment: @user326608 Yes it exits, after it exits, there is no data in the data table. That is my issue

Comment: @user326608 My bad, there is Data in DataTable